# Що таке "купа" та "лєй"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Мала нагоду побувати на кордоні Шегині - Медика. Там почула такі слова, як "**купа**" та "**лєй**". Зрозуміла, що це певна черга, але розмежувати їх не вдалося. Ймовірно, це слова *із місцевого діалекту*, але що конкретно вони означають? В Інтернеті інформації не знайшла жодної, лише те, що *лей - це молдавські гроші*. Таким чином моя знайдена інформація не має жодного стосунку до "кордонної", адже почула ці слова на кордоні "Україна - Польща" + стосуються черги як такої.

Answer (score 2):

Зі словом "купа" все зрозуміло, навіть в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/kupa) є потрібне визначення:

> 2. перен. Те саме, що група 1. Перед коршмою [корчмою] стояла досить велика купа селян (Іван Франко, VII, 1951, 323); — Ми уміємо і гуртом
>      працювати. Недарма у нас кажуть: «Де людей купа, не болить біля пупа!»
>      (Андрій Головко, II, 1957, 501); Біля них збилася жаркою купою отара
>      (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 5); — От тут стежечка, що я її вчора не
>      доглядівся, а тут купа вишеньок (Марко Вовчок, VI, 1956, 230); На
>      південь за пологими левадами та сіножатями, за купами вільхи та
>      верболозу, проти синього неба ясно вирізувалась ламана смуга горяного
>      берега Росі

Також від себе додам, що не раз чув як слово "купа" вживалося в значенні "велика кількість людей".

Набагато складніше було дізнатися значення слова "лєй" або ж "лей". Довелося навіть залізти в заблоковану мережу ВКонтакте, щоб дам почитати коментарі людей про ситуацію, яка тоді відбувалася на кордоні. І справді, я зутрів там такі коментарі:

> Станом на 8.40 цілий лей і велика купка. Десь на 2-3 год. точно.
>
> Лей вільний :-P
>
> Цілий лєй і дві купи.

Наскільки я зрозумів чергу на цьому кордоні люди називають "колєйка" або скорочено "лєй" чи "лей". Також в російській статті на [сайті Вести](https://vesti-ukr.com/lvov/7779-chelnoki-na-polskoj-granice-zarabatyvajut-na-horomy) можна побачити такі слова:

> Нам пощастило: постояли хвилин десять, і "колейка" (черга) почала
>   рухатись.

Також в [жаргоні "далекобійників"](https://mnogotransporta.ru/avto_sleng/koleika-58.html) є визначення цього слова:

> утруднений рух, але поки не пробка

Тобто, швидше за все, "купа" - це черга на пішому переході, а "лей" - на проїжджій частині. Хоча, звичайно, це лише мої здогадки і припущення.

Answer (score 0):

Лєй очевидно походить від польск. kolejka - хвіст, потік, валка, велика черга.

Купа - звичайне українське слово, означає теж: велика група людей, гора, тьма, юрба, зграя й так далі.